# How to use the Worksheets.Cells format in a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Worksheets().Cells() function to increment the cell I am referencing in a for loop. I want it to increment as such:

```
y = Worksheets("Software-Roll Up (VSL)").Range("G1") - 1
For x = 0 To y
    a = 8 + 2 * x
    reference = Worksheets("Software-Roll Up (VSL)").Cells(a, 2)
    myrange = Worksheets("Monthly Cobra Data").Range("J2:O1000000")
    marks1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 5, False)
    marks2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 6, False)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4 + x, 2) = marks1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4 + x, 3) = marks2
Next x
```

The code returns an empty value when I try to print my variable "reference." I am not sure if there is other syntax available to change this.

I am expecting to pass the String value associated with the cells allocated to the "reference" variable to the VLookup function parsing through a range of cells. When I change the Worksheets().Cells() function to a Worksheets().Range() function, the code runs, but I cannot easily increment the cell position using the Range feature.

Comment: maybe `set myrange=` instead of `myrange=`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Offset property of the Range object to increment cells in Excel VBA. For example, "ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select" will select the cell one row down and one column to the right of the active cell.

To increment cell values in a range by 1 with VBA Excel, you can use a loop to go through each cell in the range and increment its value by 1 using "myCell = myCell + 1".

You can also get a cell’s position within a range by subtracting the top left cell’s row and column from the target cell’s row and column respectively.

The following link should help you.

1. [Increment Cell Values in a Range by 1 with VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521576/increment-cell-values-in-a-range-by-1-with-vba-excel)
2. [How do I increment cell in Excel VBA script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382080/how-do-i-increment-cell-in-excel-vba-script)
3. [How do I get a cell's position within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844535/how-do-i-get-a-cells-position-within-a-range)

One more thing that I noticed that it looks like you're trying to use the "Worksheets().Cells()" function to dynamically reference cells in your loop.
One issue with your code might be the way you're setting the value of the reference variable. You're using the Cells function, which takes row and column arguments as integers, but you're passing a string variable a as the row argument. You should convert a to an integer using the "CInt()" function before passing it to the Cells function.

Here's the code with correction:

```
Dim y As Integer, a As Integer
Dim reference As String, myrange As Range, marks1 As Variant, marks2 As Variant
Dim x As Integer

y = Worksheets("Software-Roll Up (VSL)").Range("G1").Value - 1
For x = 0 To y
    a = 8 + 2 * x
    reference = Worksheets("Software-Roll Up (VSL)").Cells(a, 2).Value
    Set myrange = Worksheets("Monthly Cobra Data").Range("J2:O1000000")
    marks1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 5, False)
    marks2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 6, False)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4 + x, 2).Value = marks1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4 + x, 3).Value = marks2
Next x
```

Note that I also declared all variables and added the .Value property to the cells being written to in "Worksheets("Sheet1")".

Comment: So I tried this and I keep getting the error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class." I'd imagine this is because it does not like the type of data being passed into the line:                                                                                                         
marks1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 5, False)

Comment: I should also note the "reference" variable is capturing the value in Cells(a,2) and Cells(a+1,2) since the string I want populates 2 merged cells. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi Ryan, the error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class." usually occurs when the VLookup function cannot find a match for the specified reference value in the lookup table. To avoid this error, you can use the IFERROR function to check if the VLookup function returns an error value, & handle it appropriately. For example, marks1 = application.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(reference, myrange, 5, False), "Not Found"), modify "marks2" similar to "marks1"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. I always recommend using variables to refer to worksheets and ranges wherever you can to make the code more legible - also it can improve performance. I also always use Option Explicit in modules so that you are forced to declare all variables before use - this really helps to avoid bugs arising from mistyping variable names.

Warning, this code has not been tested, there are likely to be bugs.

```
Public Sub lookupMarks()

    '// Get references to the worksheets
    Dim wsRollup As Worksheet: Set wsRollup = Worksheets("Software-Roll Up (VSL)")
    Dim wsCobra As Worksheet: Set wsCobra = Worksheets("Monthly Cobra Data")
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet: Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '// The references to be looked up are in column 2 of Rollup sheet
    Dim rRollupRefs As Range: Set rRollupRefs = wsRollup.Columns(2)

    '// The marks to be looked up are in this area of cobra sheet, and the
    '// references are in column 1 of this area
    Dim rMarksRange As Range: Set rMarksRange = wsCobra.Range("J2:O1000000")
    Dim rRefsColumn As Range: Set rRefsColumn = rMarksRange.Columns(1)
    
    
    '// Get the limit for the for loop is in the Rollup sheet cell G1
    Dim y As Long: y = wsRollup.Range("G1").Value - 1
    
    '// Variables to use in the for loop
    Dim x As Long, a As Long, refToFind As Variant, rOutputCell As Range, iMatchRow As Integer
    
    '// Run the loop
    For x = 0 To y
        a = 8 + 2 * x
        
        '// Get the reference value to be looked up from the Rollup sheet
        refToFind = rRollupRefs.Cells(a).Value
        
        
        '// Find the row in the references column range that matches the
        '// ref value. Match is more useful than VLookup in vba
        '// because it returns a row number that can be re-used
        iMatchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(refToFind, rRefsColumn, 0)
        
        '// Get a reference to the output cell in the output worksheet
        '// and get the values from col 5 and 6 of the matching row in
        '// marks area of the Cobra sheet
        Set rOutputcell = wsOutput.Cells(4 + x, 2)
        rOutputcell.Value = rMarksRange.Cells(iMatchRow, 5).Value
        rOutputcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = rMarksRange.Cells(iMatchRow, 6).Value
    
    Next x
    
End Sub
```